# HDMI specification - AVI InfoFrame Version 2

Tags: hdmi

The AVI InfoFrame Specification Packet Contents
( Data byte 6-13 ) refer to four parameters respectively ( End of Top Bar ) ( Start of Bottom Bar ) ( End of Left Bar ) ( Start of Right Bar ).

However these 4 parameters did not appear anywhere in the whole specification, any one have any idea what these 4 parameters refer to ?

Thank you for any input or pointers to more detail documents.

Comment: Seems I got the answer from another document EIA-CEA-861-B,  it says these parameters are for on-screen text.  ( I don't understand why they need these parameters, seems over complicating things, if any expert has info to share, please enlight me :).  Thanks )  For the prior question, I think I had the answer already.